# Change search URL indexing from www to non-www

Tags: google-search, search-engines

In the Google Search Console, I submitted both URLs (www and non-www) for indexing. It seems that the www version got indexed first and the non-www got 'Google-selected canonical'.

Is it possible to switch to a non-www URL while making the www canonical without messing up current search query positions?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a canonical link to point to the non-www one.

Even then its a suggestion from you and Google may do its own thing.

> **Canonical**
> A canonical URL is the URL of the best representative page from a group of duplicate pages, according to Google. For example, if you have two URLs for the same page (such as example.com?dress=1234 and example.com/dresses/1234), Google chooses one as canonical. Similarly, if you have multiple pages that are nearly identical, Google can group them together (for example, pages that differ only by the sorting or filtering of the contents, such as by price or item color) and choose one as canonical. Google can only index the canonical URL from a set of duplicate pages.
>
> A duplicate can be in a different domain than its canonical (such as example.com/mypage and example2.com/myduplicate).

From [support.google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/10347851?hl=en)

Comment: Setting the canonical doesn't usually affect search positions much, but in some cases it does.  I'd consider it the safer option in regards to SEO compared to implementing redirects.